# htaccess RewriteRule Issue - pulsecms

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess (Using PulseCMS)

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^reviews-page-([^-]*)$ ?page=$1&p=reviews [L]
RewriteRule ^reviews-([^-]*)+? ?d=$1&p=reviews [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Currently when I go to a review my url would look like this:

http://domain.com/reviews-1-title

I would like to rewrite it to:

http://domain.com/reviews/title

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just modify your existing rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^reviews[-/]([^-]+) ?d=$1&p=reviews [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^reviews-page-([^-]+)$ ?page=$1&p=reviews [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, I see what you did there but doesn't work on my end.
Maybe I forgot to mention that my url is replacing spaces with dashes like

http://domain.com/reviews-1-custom-title-this-is-a-demo

Comment: I changed it to RewriteRule ^reviews[-/]([^-]*)+? ?d=$1&p=reviews [L]
and it works almost as I want. just this 1- is still there

Comment: So out of `/reviews-1-custom-title-this-is-a-demo` do you want only `custom-title-this-is-a-demo` in `$_GET['d']`?

Comment: I want /reviews/custom-title-this-is-a-demo

Comment: How should `/reviews/custom-title-this-is-a-demo` be rewritten to? Will it be `/?d=custom-title-this-is-a-demo&p=reviews` ?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you, but I think I get it, this ?d= (right now id's 1,2,3) I dont think it is possible to remove from this url right? because it doesnt know what review to look for I will just leave it like this.. atleast /reviews/1-title-demo-test works so I got the extra / 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's right above rule will work fine for `/reviews/1-title-demo-test` since you must not remove `id` from URL to make it work.